# ReactJS useState, onClick show InfoWindow

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, onclick, use-state

In my react google maps code I am not able to set onclick open InfoWindow. I am referring to this tutorial: https://youtu.be/WZcxJGmLbSo?t=1545

my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "@react-google-maps/api"; // --> using @react package

const libraries = ["places"];
const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh",
};
const center = {
  lat: 51.103807,
  lng: 10.057477,
};


export default function App() {

const [setSState, sstate] = React.useState(null);

  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY,
    libraries,
  });

  if (loadError) return "error loading maps";
  if (!isLoaded) return "loading maps";

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={6}
        center={{ lat: 50.115509, lng: 8.690508 }}
      >
        <Marker
          position={{ lat: 51.081753, lng: 13.696073 }}
           onClick={() => {
            sstate(!setSState);
            console.log("marker clicked");
          }}
          }}
        ></Marker>
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am not able to show the marker only when clicked. What shall I do? I am hard coding the data for now. I am still new to props.

And when click the X on marker and click on the marker again it crashes. I know I have to use onCloseClick which when I tried didnt work.

[image]

Comment: Please read the [docs on `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). `useState` returns an array with the state value at index 0, and an updater function at index 1. You are using the whole array as a function.

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry about the unUpvoting your answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`useState` Hook docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

The hook will give you a state variable to use, and a function that can be used to update that variable.

At the top of the component you want to have:

```
const [centerState, setCenterState] = useState(null);
```

and then you can use this in the Marker to update the state:

```
onClick={() => setCenterState(center)}
```

That will update the state, but in your code you are currently getting `center` from an object assigned outside of the component, you might want to think about what you are going to set in that state.